# Checkpoint during Backup

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g, checkpoint

Can database process make automatic checkpoint when I'm in process of copying files during

```
ALTER DATABASE BEGIN BACKUP;
```

and

```
ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP;
```

You can assume that process of copying files will last for very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can.

As mentioned in 
[Making User-Managed Backups of Online Read/Write Tablespaces](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/osbackup.htm#GUID-73283C54-4C12-4FDB-9CC5-515BFEB44CE8) copies of the datafile blocks modified are written to th redo logs. But checkpoints are no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat begs the question of why not use rman for your backups instead of user managed backups.  rman has been the robust solution since at least 9i, and here we are with 12c being mature.